# Get Karate request data using another util service

Tags: testing, bdd, karate

One of the param for my API is security related and linked to the environment on which the test would run , essentially it will be dynamic.
Since this is security related, I have an internal rest API that provides this data. 
I want to understand what is the effective way of getting this data in Karate feature?

I have tried two different ways:
1. Defined a java util and invoke the java type and def variable for holding the data

2. Defined a Util method as part of karate-config.js

In karate-config.js

```
function getSomeData(someValue) {

    return Java.type('xyz.abc.util.MyUtil');
}
```

In the feature file
defined a JS

```
* def dataFromJS = read('classpath:com/xyz/util/js_that_invokes_rest.js')
```

I want to understand if there is a pattern of how this should be done or if there is an explicit support in Karate for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an internal rest API

Well. Did you just forget that Karate is all about making REST requests !? :)

Please create a re-usable feature, make that REST call, define the variables that you need and now you can call it from other features.

Please refer to the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-other-feature-files